# Interacting with two models - generating api ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create an api rails application and i am encountering some problemes.

i got two models

- A Shop with the following attributes name:string, localisation:text, size:integer
- Employee with the following attributes name:string social_number:integer age:integer shop:references

A Shop can have multiple references so i thought about using belongs_to in the Employe modeland has_many in the Shop model

I am trying to create the following request **POST /shops**

the response should show the followings about the data of the shops

```
{
  name: String, 
  localisation: text,  
  age: integer,  
  employees: List[employee]  
}
```

And concerning the data of an employee

```
{
  name: String,
  social_number: integer,
  age:integer
}
```

I know that I can write `Shop.employees.create(name: "Yves", social_number: "12342323", age: 29)` and I can see that it works in the DB.

But when I am writing the post request in the create function, how can I show the employee attribute in the body response? I can only show the attributes of the shops i.e name, localisation, age.

Thanks to the belongs_to association, I have the shop_id in the table of Employees but I don't have anything in the `Shop` table. How can I make a link in order to show the employees characteristics that belongs to the shop?

I'm using Rails.

Thanks all, and sorry for the long post.

Tell me if I was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would have different API calls to create a shop and an employee.  So call it to create a shop, and get the shop id back.  Then use this shop id in following calls to create the employees.

Alternatively, creating a shop with an number of employees, send the employee attributes as an array in the create shop request.

```
{
  name: String, 
  localisation: text,  
  age: integer,  
  employees: [
    {
      name: String,
      social_number: integer,
      age:integer
    },
    {
      name: String,
      social_number: integer,
      age:integer
    }
  ]
}
```

The response should be similar but with ids.

```
{
  id: integer,
  name: String, 
  localisation: text,  
  age: integer,  
  employees: [
    {
      id: integer,
      name: String,
      social_number: integer,
      age:integer
    },
    {
      id: integer,
      name: String,
      social_number: integer,
      age:integer
    }
  ]
}
```

The employee hashes might optionally include the shop_id attribute.  It doesn't hurt anything.